# Differentiate Registry Key from Value paths

Tags: powershell, registry

Is there an equivalent of `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` and `[System.IO.FileInfo]` for differentiating Registry Keys from Values? I want to evaluate a path and log for the user what the final target of the path is.

So far, this is what I have, and it's kinda ugly.

```
$path = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SomeJunkHereToTestFailure'
try {
    if ((Get-Item -path:$path -errorAction:stop).GetType().name -eq 'RegistryKey') {
        'Registry Key'
    }
} catch {
    try {
        if ((Get-ItemProperty -path:(Split-Path $path -parent) -name:(Split-Path $path -leaf) -errorAction:stop).GetType().name -eq 'PSCustomObject') {
            'Registry Value'
        }
    } catch {
        'What is this?'
    }
}
```

Hoping for something more elegant and also consistently correct.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so after digging around for awhile, *canonically speaking*, this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Path\To\Something
```

Is *always* a path to a key.

Look at `reg.exe query`.  Look at how `Get-ItemProperty` works.  Notice in `regedit.exe` that you can copy key names, but not a "path" to a specific value. Look at how .reg files are written.  Look at [`Registry.GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Registry.SetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx).  Or `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey().GetValue()`.  Microsoft clearly thinks that registry paths always point to keys.

If you have software that's using `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Path\To\A\Value` to refer to a value in the registry, then they're not using standard registry paths that Windows understands.

That's why you run these the way you do:

```
reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName" 
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name "ProductName"
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::LocalMachine.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').GetValue('ProductName')
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::GetValue('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion','ProductName', $false)
```

That last one is nice because it doesn't error.  If it can't find the value, it returns the third argument.  It does, however, require the long hive name at the start as far as I can tell.

So, `Test-Path -Container` can tell you if it's a key.  `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue()` can tell you if it's a value... with some manipulation.

---

Original answer (THIS DOES NOT WORK):

Use `Test-Path`:

```
$path = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SomeJunkHereToTestFailure'

# Is it a Key?
Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container

# Is it a Value?
Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Leaf
```

Comment: This is a double interesting. First, I had been burned by Test-Path a while ago, when trying to address File System stuff. So I didn't even think to try it for Registry stuff, which is a mistake. That said, SS64.com says it always returns false on a Value, though it works on a Key.

Comment: @Gordon Huh.  You're right it does seem to do that.  Dang, I was certain I tested it both ways, too.

Answer (score 0):

As for...

> Is there an equivalent of [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] and [System.IO.FileInfo]

Not that I've ever seen or heard of to date.

However, take a look at the below to see if they can fit your need or you may be ableto tweak them to accomplish your goals.

> Powershell Registry Cmdlets utilizing the .Net StdRegProv
>
> This Script is a collection of PowerShell cmdlets that can be run in either x86 or x64 processes to handle common registry operations utilizing alternate registry views. This script is compatible with PowerShell versions 2.0 or later.
>
> Download RegistryCmdlets.ps1 
>   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Powershell-Registry-19689888

Or of course is back to writing your own as you are posting here:

See also as you look at your effor to cultivate your own:

> Registry Cmdlets: First Steps with CDXML
>
> In this post, I’ll show you how to get started with CDXML. Before that, though, I’d better explain CDXML...
>
> Cmdlet definition XML (CDXML) is a way to create a Windows PowerShell module from a WMI class by using the cmdlets-over-objects technology that was introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0. As usual, it’s always easier to show you an example:
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/02/03/registry-cmdlets-first-steps-with-cdxml/
>
> Registry Cmdlets: Working with the Registry
>
> The bad news is that there aren’t any cmdlets for working with the registry. There’s a Registry provider, which means you can use the Item and ItemProperty cmdlets to manage the local registry—but there aren’t any specific registry cmdlets associated with the provider.
>
> The good news is that we can adopt the approach that many teams at Microsoft have taken and create our own by using cmdlet definition XML (CDXML). A Common Information Model (CIM) class is wrapped in some fairly simple XML and published as a Windows PowerShell module. If you look in the Modules folder on a computer running Windows 8.1, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 R2, or Windows Server 2012, you will find many files with a CDXML extension:
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/02/02/registry-cmdlets-working-with-the-registry

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the premise of your question: **Ending a registry path - composed of *key* names - with a *value* name is *not supported*** - at least neither with the .NET Framework registry types nor with `reg.exe` nor with PowerShell's registry drive provider.

For instance, to refer to value `WindowSize` of registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors`, you CANNOT use the following path:

```
# NOT a valid path, because 'WindowSize' is a *value*, not a *key*.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\WindowSize
```

Even if you yourself decide to support such paths in your functions (and there may be utilities that similarly accept that), note that they are *ambiguous*, because a given registry key can have *both* a value and a subkey with a given name.

With that limitation in mind, your own code from your question is probably the best you can do (though it can be streamlined a little).

---

> Is there an equivalent of [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] and [System.IO.FileInfo] for differentiating Registry Keys from Values?

- The equivalent of `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` (filesystem directory) is `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` (registry key).
- By contrast, `[System.IO.FileInfo]` (filesystem file) has NO counterpart for registry *values*:

  - Registry values are represented as *properties* of registry items (keys) in the PS registry drive provider rather than *items* in their own right, and such properties are (awkwardly) represented as non-specific `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` instances.
  - Similarly, registry values have *no* type representation in the .NET Framework (you only request their *data* by name).

Fundamentally, **in terms of object models, registry values do *not* correspond to filesystem files**; read on for more.

---

#### Optional reading: how the registry object model maps onto PowerShell drive-provider concepts in contrast with the filesystem object model

It comes down to this: **in the filesystem, a directory's *files* are *child items*, whereas in the registry, a key's *values* are *properties of that key*.**
Only *container-type* children are represented as child *items* in both providers (sub-*directories* in the case of the filesystem provider, sub-*keys* in case of the registry provider).

- In the context of the **`FileSystem` provider**, ***files* and *directories* are *both* (sub-types of) *items***.

  - Files are represented as `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances, and directories as `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`.
  - A *leaf* item is *invariably* of subtype *file*, whereas a *container* (interior) item is *invariably* of subtype *directory* (folder).

    - Therefore, you can **use `Test-Path -PathType Leaf` to test for a *file*** and **`Test-Path -PathType Container` to test for a *directory***.
- In the context of the **`Registry` provider**, it is ***only keys* that are *items*.**

  - *Keys* are represented as `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` instances.
  - Since *all* keys are (potentially) *containers*, **the registry provider has no concept of a *leaf* item**.

    - Therefore, **use of `Test-Path -PathType <type>` with a *registry path* is pointless**, 
      because with `-PathType Leaf` the result is *always* `$False`, and with `-PathType Container` it is *always* `$True`.
  - By contrast, **registry *values* are represented as *properties*** (the equivalent of what the last-modified date is to a filesystem item, for instance).

    - Use the `*-ItemProperty*` cmdlets to read and write registry values.