# How to check the existence of registry key in HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG

Tags: powershell

How to check the presence of registry key named "Mon12345678" under `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\ {CD73268F-4662-42EC-80F6-182E03DE7017}\0000` regsitry hive? We can validate till `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO` directly and then run random check under "Video" until we get the sub registry key called "Mon12345678"?

I tried the below code snippet

```
Test-Path -Path "HKCC:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\ *\Mon12345678" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

But the result shows false even though the sub registry hive is found. How to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` registry hive is *not* predefined as a PowerShell drive name `HKCC:`, so unless you defined such a drive yourself with `New-PSDrive`, it won't exist.

`(Get-PSDrive -psProvider Registry).Name` shows you which registry-based drives are defined; by default, it is only `HKLM:` (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`) and `HKCU:` (`HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG`).

**Short of defining your own `HKCC:` drive, you can prefix a registry hive name with `registry::` (the provider name)** in order to target a hive; e.g.:

```bsh
# Test the existence of a key known to exist in the HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG registry hive,
# using provider prefix 'registry::'
PS> Test-Path -Path 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control'
True
```

---

Therefore, to **test the existence of a *subkey* named `Mon12345678`** across all subkeys (`*`) of key `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO`, use the following:

```
$keyPath = 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO'
Test-Path -Path "$keyPath\*\Mon12345678"
```

---

If, by contrast, you want to **test the existence of a *value* (a *property* of a registry key) named `Mon12345678`**, you cannot use a single `Test-Path` call, because `Test-Path` can only operate on *key* paths, not paths ending in *value names*.

<sup>See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48799525/45375) for background information.</sup>

```
$keyPath = 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO'
[bool] (Get-ItemProperty -EA ignore "$keyPath\*" 'Mon12345678')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

To search part of the registry, use the following syntax:

```
REG Query HKxx\subkey [/D|/K|/V] /F "search_pattern" /S [/E] [/C]
```

To search an entire registry hive, just omit the subkey:

```
REG Query HKxx [/D|/K|/V] /F "search_pattern" /S [/E] [/C]
```

[Source of the solution and full post can be found here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/regsearch.php)